# How to get the value from a table cell

Tags: migradoc

I have a table I created and am most interested in the "costs" column. I could have more than one row of data in which I would have multiple costs and I want to add those up and put the result in the table cell next to "Total." I saw a method called GetValue(); but not sure if that is what I am looking for or how to use it. My thinking is that migradoc has a method where you can get the value of a table cell in which I would store that in a variable. And where I create the "Total" row, I would use that variable to display the total. So how would I do that?

My code:

```
/define header of table
        Row row = table.AddRow();
        row.HeadingFormat = true;
        Cell cell = row.Cells[0];
        cell.AddParagraph("Customer Name");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        cell = row.Cells[1];
        cell.AddParagraph("Date Created");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        cell = row.Cells[2];
        cell.AddParagraph("Description");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        cell = row.Cells[3];
        cell.AddParagraph("Due Date");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        cell = row.Cells[4];
        cell.AddParagraph("Billable Hours");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        cell = row.Cells[5];
        cell.AddParagraph("Costs");
        cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;



        //define a row of data in the table
        foreach (TicketView1 ticket in SampleTickets)
        {
            row = table.AddRow();

            cell = row.Cells[0];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.customer_name);

            cell = row.Cells[1];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.date_created.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            cell = row.Cells[2];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.description);

            cell = row.Cells[3];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.due_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            cell = row.Cells[4];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.billable_hrs.ToString());
        }

        cell = row.Cells[5];
        cell.AddParagraph("$60.00");



        //add invisible row as a space line to the table
        row = table.AddRow();
        row.Borders.Visible = false;

        //add the subtotal row
        row = table.AddRow();
        row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Sub Total:");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;
        cell = row.Cells[5];



        //add tax row
        row = table.AddRow();
        row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("TAX:");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;

        //add total
        row = table.AddRow();
        row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("TOTAL:");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;




    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer by simple creating a count variable and then inside my forEach loop just adding that sum plus my dummy data which would be 60. Then right where I created my "totals" row, right underneath it I added into the cell that variable which contains the count data.

My forEach loop and count variable

```
double sum = 0;
        foreach (TicketView1 ticket in SampleTickets)
        {
            row = table.AddRow();

            cell = row.Cells[0];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.customer_name);

            cell = row.Cells[1];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.date_created.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            cell = row.Cells[2];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.description);

            cell = row.Cells[3];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.due_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            cell = row.Cells[4];
            cell.AddParagraph(ticket.billable_hrs.ToString());

            cell = row.Cells[5];
            cell.AddParagraph("$60.00");
            sum = sum + 60;
        }
```

Where I added the total row and appended the data to the totals cell:

```
//add total
        row = table.AddRow();
        row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("TOTAL:");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;

        row.Cells[5].AddParagraph(sum.ToString("$0.00"));
```